# Ruby on rails - Read from database with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am fairly new to ruby on rails and can't understand how I read a attribute or a bit of text from the database.

I want a user to decide a display name for their account by a text field that will write the display name to the database, (if you can shine some light on how to write to database with a form it's highly appreciated). When it have been written to the database I want it to be displayed back at the user in the view.

So the question follows:

How do I read a attribute or a string of text from the database with ActiveRecord and then display it in the view?

Below is some code that might be useful, just ask if I am missing something.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessor :username

  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  has_many :posts
end
```

**profile.html.erb** (where I want to print the string)

The comments in the code below are code snippets I have tried

```
<%= render 'partials/meny' %>
   <article id="profile" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
     <!--<img src="#"/>-->
     <h1>Profile for <%= current_user.email %></h1>
       <div id="main">

         <%# @users = User.new(:username => 'gaming') %>

         <%# form_for @users do |f| %>
           <%# f.text_field :username %>
           <%# f.submit 'Set username' %>
         <%# end %>
         <%= @user.username %>
       <% User.find_each do |model_var| %>
         <tr>
           <td><%= model_var.username %></td>
         </tr>
       <% end %>

    </div>
  <%= render 'partials/footer' %>
</article>
```

I have tried this to display the username with `<%= @user.username %>` but to no avail, what am I missing?

**Proof that the string exists in the database**

[The selected string in the bottom right corner is the string I want printed out on the view above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPDqU.png)

I don't know either if I need a controller for this, I have read the activerecord documentation and the database documentation. I have read and tried rails querying also but to no avail. I have also tried and looked on [Different Ways to set attributes in activerecord](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/)

I have tried creating a object of the model and call it from/by that but it returns nothing. Examples are in the rails ActiveRecord documentation.

**EDIT**

**Problem is solved**

I just needed to remove attr_accessor :username like Iceman said and then use Devise's current_user.id to get the current user and then find the user's username with <%= user.username %>

The code solution that prints the username to the view:

```
<% @user = User.find(current_user.id %>
<%= @user.username %>
```

Comment: Remove `attr_accessor :username`

Comment: @Iceman Thank you a lot! This really sent me in the right direction! :D